# SQLDriver not initialized with server version

Tags: sitefinity

I am getting the following error on sitefinity 4.4

> SQLDriver not initialized with server version.

I checked on sitefinity forums but I cannot find any fix for this issue

SQLDriver not initialized with server version.

Description:

> An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details:

> System.InvalidOperationException: SQLDriver not initialized with server version.

Source Error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

```
[InvalidOperationException: SQLDriver not initialized with server version.]
   OpenAccessRuntime.Relational.RelationalMetaDataBuilder.findMatchingJdbcColumn(DataObjectsExtension[] nested) +398
   OpenAccessRuntime.Relational.RelationalMetaDataBuilder.createJdbcSimpleField(FieldMetaData fmd) +204
   OpenAccessRuntime.Relational.RelationalMetaDataBuilder.createJdbcField(FieldMetaData fmd, Boolean quietParam) +125

[MetadataException: The metadata for field 'id' of class 'Telerik.Sitefinity.Metadata.Model.MetaAttribute' cannot be initialized: SQLDriver not initialized with server version.]
   DynamicModule.ns.Wrapped_OpenAccessMetaDataProvider_904ca528250e4b188a43261dbbe077b6.Initialize(String providerName, NameValueCollection config, Type managerType) +405
   Telerik.Sitefinity.Data.ManagerBase`1.InstantiateProvider(IDataProviderSettings providerSettings, Type providerType, ExceptionPolicyName policy, ManagerBase`1 manager) +1976
   Telerik.Sitefinity.Data.ManagerBase`1.InstantiateProvider(IDataProviderSettings providerSettings, ExceptionPolicyName policy, ManagerBase`1 manager) +74
   Telerik.Sitefinity.Data.ManagerBase`1.SetProvider(String providerName, String transactionName) +526
```

Comment: When are you seeing this error? Is it on an asp.net "yellow screen"? or when you run the Project Manager, or SDK? or in visual studio? Can you provide the full text of the error and what steps you took to produce it? If I know more I'll do my best to help!

Comment: Hi Josh this is the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

by any chance are you running this in Visual Studio 2012? I believe the version of OpenAccess in Sitefinity 4.4 is not compatible wih VS2012 and throws this error if you run it from that environment (or asp.net 4.5 in IIS).

if this is the case try opening in VS2010, then hopefully you'll be able to upgrade to the latest version to support VS2012.

if this is not the case at all, I would definitely suggest sending this as a ticket to Sitefinity support so they can take a close look at your project!

I hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this helps someone:

I encountered this error, not using Sitefinity, but in a rather old app that uses some of the same Telerik libraries that are also used in Sitefinity. The app runs fine using SQL Server 2005 and 2008 R2, but fails with 2012 and up.

Something in the library is not recognizing any SQL Server version above 2008 R2. (From clues in the traceback, it appears that one part of the library stores the SQL version, and another part looks at it. The first part doesn't recognize SQL 2012 and up, so it just doesn't store anything.)

The obvious implication is that a more recent version of the library is needed. We did not write or build the app, so unfortunately we can't do this until/unless we can get (or make) a version of the app that uses an updated library.

But for the original question, either a newer version of Sitefinity, or using an earlier version of SQL Server, might work.

Anyway, maybe this information can help someone that might be seeing the same message.